# Is it possible to dynamically arrange card items to the top?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, grid-layout

```js
var size = document.getElementsByClassName("info-box");

for (const key in size) {
    if (size.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        const element = size[key];
        element.addEventListener('click', (function () {
            return select(element);
        }), false);
    }
}

function select(element) {
    element.classList.toggle("selected");
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
main {
    background-color: #121212;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    gap: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
    
}

.info-box {
    /* Design */
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.62);

    /* Flex Layout */
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    
    /* Content */
    padding: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;

    transition: 1s;
    
}

.info-box.selected{
    width: 510px;
    height: 510px;  

}
```

```html
    <main>
        <div class="info-box selected"></div>
        <div class="info-box"></div>
        <div class="info-box"></div>
        <div class="info-box"></div>
        <div class="info-box"></div>
        <div class="info-box"></div>
    </main>
```

I'm trying to build a card layout which allows an arbitary amount of cards.
The cards all have a fixed width and height. The cards should be able to grow double in height and width when a butto is pressed. This transition is animated.
I tried building this layout with flexbox, but the cards leave gaps in my grid. The cards should fill
these gaps when one of the cards gets resized.